# Resizable Form C#

Tags: c#, .net, forms, postgresql, resize

im new in all this programing stuff and theres a few things i dont know and ive been looking for the answer and cant find it.

*Is there a way to make a form that can be resizable without it losing the "form", or just using algorithm?

*Once the program is finished. How do i "export" the database(postgresql) so the user can access to it. Like in a installer or that kind of things!

Ill be thankful!

Comment: losing the "form"? Don't understand what you mean!

Comment: The layout of the form, i mean, for instance, i have a datagridview with a size of 640*400 in a size of 800*600 for the form. But, when i maximized it to 1280*800, the datagrid still 640*400. Is there a way to make that increase his size with the form? or just with algorith and events.

Comment: And sorry to the one that keeps downvoting me.. im sorry im learning and in ur awesomeness this question is too stupid for u. Im learning this w/o any tutor or help other than the internet!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make the form resizable, you just set the Forms **FormBorderStyle** Property to Sizable. If you mean without losing the form, as in restrict it being resized too small, then you set the forms **MinimumSize** property.

---

Your other question, to deploy a postgressql database, here are the basic steps, you can google around for this info:

1. Use the Postgres windows installer to install 8.2.7
2. Import all the application's databases.
3. Using the NSIS Installer Generation app:

a) Include all files under c:\program files\postgresql... in the project;
b) Use NSIS utilities to install the PostgreSQL service in a custom manner.

I do this on a non-standard port so that if the user already has PG, it does not clobber the existing install.

Comment: Oh! thx!! its just that im new and maybe im not typing the exact words to find it! The form is in a 800*600, cant resize. I just want it to be resizable, lets say 1280*800 and the form still look the "same" u know, like any normal program

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look at the Dock and Anchor properties of the controls on the form. If you set a control's Dock property to DockStyle.Fill, it'll take up all the space in the container it's in and if the container gets bigger or smaller, the docked control will get bigger and smaller with it. For what you're doing, you'll probably want to just use the Anchor property. Set it to include all (Top, Bottom, Left and Right) on your DataGridView and that will make that grid expand and contract with the form, without filling up all the space.